# How do I disable the prompt to discard or keep downloads in Google Chrome on Mac OS?

Tags: high-sierra, google-chrome, data-transfer, settings, google

I have seen other posts asking similar questions to this but they were for Ubuntu and Windows. All answers were exclusive to the respective operating system. I have not seen something that will work for Mac OS users to get the desired result: Disabling the prompt to Discard or to Keep (requiring annoying user intervention to initiate the download) so that downloads just download regardless of their extension type.

I have found a solution to [Disable Google Chrome's Safe Browsing](https://www.ghacks.net/2014/07/15/fix-chromes-safe-browsing-feature-blocking-downloads-browser/) feature but that's not what I'm after. Downloads still require user intervention for some file types (such as DMGs which typically contain Applications)

I'm hoping there's a simple solution to this annoyance.

Here's a screenshot of the prompt.

[image: There is a yellow triangular symbol with a white exclamation point character inside. The prompt reads "This type of file can harm your computer. Do you want to keep capti (1).dmg anyway? Two buttons are present, one says "Discard" the other says "Keep"]

Comment: This has actually got worse recently. I was seeing this prompt, but now the only button that shows id 'Discard' and '...'.
You have to go to the 'Show All' download page in order to see the 'Keep' button!

Comment: I’ve been experiencing that same issue too, definitely an annoying bug.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=823108

Comment: Now fixed with Chrome 66.0.3359.139

Comment: @SimonMeusel FIxed how? I still have the prompt in version 117.0.5938.149

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised no one has provided an answer to this. So I will share the solution I've been using for half a year or so.

I personally use [Neat Download Manager](https://www.neatdownloadmanager.com/index.php/en/). Be sure to install the related extension and look through the settings. This approach completely bypasses the Google Download manager and offers the bonus benefit of accelerated parallel downloads and resumability (if the file host supports it).

There are a few situations where downloads will not work with the Neat Download manager, in this case a tip for you, hold the delete key as you click a download button in the browser, and the download will commence via the browser's built-in download manager.

Cons: It's not a beautiful download manager. Safari extension is not worth using (duplicate download in Neat + Safari built-in DL manager) Firefox and Chrome extensions are fine though.

Pros: It is lean for a Desktop application with a GUI and does not require user intervention to download something.

Until there's something better this is what I'm using.

I have no connection to the neat download manger project, and I have not been payed or compensated in any way for promoting them as a solution. I offer this simply out of my own interest for finding a solution to how Chrome's download manager requires user-intervention to complete a download.

I will happily select someone else's answer as soon as a better option comes to light.